# Importance of sound quotes

Tags: film, directors, quote

I'm looking for quotes by famous filmakers about the importance of good audio in film.  I've seen the David Lynch one:

"Films are 50 percent visual and 50 percent sound. Sometimes sound even overplays the visual."

And Danny Boyle:

"The first movie we made, when we made Shallow Grave, we had this discussion, because we had a million pounds and we were all just working out how to spend it. I said to them, we talked about, why was it, when were looking at movies in Britain, the British movies looked shit, and the American movies looked great, even if they weren’t great movies, they looked great. Why is it? And it was sound. American movies know you spend money on sound. Just because you can’t see it doesn’t mean you shouldn’t spend money on it. We ring-fenced money for Shallow Grave, proper money. Because we ran out of money, of course, for everything else. But we didn’t spend the sound money. And that was one of the reasons the film was a success and looked like it supposedly revitalized the British film industry. It’s only because we spent a lot of money on sound! [laughs] We dealt with it properly rather than threw it away, y’know."

Anybody know of any others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Walter Murch is always a good source of 'sound in film' quotes.  Here's one, answering the question: 'Has sound in film led us to hear the world differently?' from [this interview](http://www2.yk.psu.edu/~jmj3/murchfq.htm).

Murch: "In the same way that painting, or looking at paintings, makes you see the world in a different way, listening to interestingly arranged sounds makes you hear differently."

Answer (score 0):

This is actually games but its similar

"Sound is what truly convinces the mind is in a place, in other words hearing is believing" Jesse Schell The Art of Game Design